# JSON Array Won't Map In Jersey

Tags: java, c#, json, jersey

I am building a Jersey Server with Maven Project and I have everything working fine except when I attempt to send a Request from a C# program I have that the user will be interacting with the array whose JSON appears as:

```
[{"Weight":0.0,"RFIDCode":0},{"Weight":55.5,"RFIDCode":1}]
```

When I send the code to the server I end up with an empty Java Array 
My C# code is below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;
using RestSharp;

namespace POSTJSONList
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<ExampleMen> people = new List<ExampleMen>();
            JsonSerializer ser = new JsonSerializer();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                ExampleMen person1 = new ExampleMen(i, i * 55.5);
                people.Add(person1);
            }
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(people);
            Console.WriteLine(json);
            Console.ReadLine();
            var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:9998");
            var request = new RestRequest("/trash", Method.POST);
            request.AddJsonBody(json);
            client.ExecuteAsync(request, response => {
                Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
            });
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

My Java Code is below

```
@POST
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    //@Param recycleList a list of all of the data that we have collected
    public String createtrash_records(trashpickup_type trashList[]){
        System.out.println("Im Here Guys!!!!");
        // TODO update this to take the information we pass through to it and create individual objects based on it. 
        // TODO modify to return success code
        billing billSystem = billing.getInstance();
        systemTotalsTrash sysTotalsTrashSystem = systemTotalsTrash.getInstance();
        int i = 1;
        for(trashpickup_type alpha : trashList)
        {   
            System.out.println(alpha.getRFIDCode() + alpha.getWeight());
            i++;
            /*try {
                billSystem.updateBillingRecord(rec.getUserName(), 0, rec.getWeight());
                sysTotalsTrashSystem.updateSystemTotals(rec.getWeight());
                getDao().createIfNotExists(rec);

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            */
        }
        return "It worked";
    }
```

The Model Code (that which the JSON is mapped to) is Here

```
package com.gallup.gethip.model;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import com.j256.ormlite.field.DatabaseField;
import com.j256.ormlite.table.DatabaseTable;

@XmlRootElement
@DatabaseTable(tableName="trash_records")
public class trashpickup_type {
    @DatabaseField(columnName = "RFIDCode")
    private int RFIDCode;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = "Weight")
    private double Weight;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = "PickedUp")
    private Date PickedUp;
    public trashpickup_type()
    {

    }
    public void setRFIDCode(int RFIDCode)
    {
        this.RFIDCode = RFIDCode;
    }
    public void setWeight(double Weight)
    {
        this.Weight = Weight;
    }
    public void setPickedUP(Date PickedUp)
    {
        this.PickedUp = PickedUp;
    }

    public double getWeight()
    {
        return Weight;
    }
    public double getRFIDCode()
    {
        return RFIDCode;
    }
    public Date getPickedUp()
    {
        return PickedUp;
    }
}
```

Any Suggestions are appreciated. I will post more information upon request if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You serialize the `people` list to json and then use `request.AddJsonBody` to add it to the request. But `AddJsonBody` will again serialize the argument to json,  so you end up with a double serialized value which - on the server side - cannot be parsed into `trashList[]`. Therefore remove the client-side serialization code and simply write

```
request.AddJsonBody(people);
```